# Scrapy Hit Login Spider Before Current Spider Crawl

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, operator-overloading

I have three spiders as below

```
Class LogInSpider(scrapy):
   name = 'DomainLogin'
   allowed_domains = ['domain.io']
   start_urls = ['https://www.domain.io/signin']
   def parse(self, response):
      return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
      })

Class SelectProduct(scrapy):
   # Crawl and select products

Class AddProductToCart(scrapy):
   # Form request to cart

Here when I run spider "SelectProduct", I want to first hit "LogInSpider" and get its follow request to "SelectProduct" parse() method and at last hit "AddProductToCart" spider.

I tried using CrawlerRunner() as well but the issue I am facing with these is, scrapy request object gets changed(not same derived from login) when it comes to "SelectProduct", check below code out.

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(LogInSpider)
    yield runner.crawl(SelectProduct)
    yield runner.crawl(AddProductToCart)
    reactor.stop()
configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings = get_project_settings())
crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Any suggestion in a change in the workflow will be accepted.

Note: Above three spiders needs to be in a separate class in order to keep code centralized.

Answer (score 0):

For case like Yours - it is expected that Login, SelectProduct, AddProductToCart functionality implemented inside single Spider Class.

Scrapy doesn't have built-in possibility to transfer data and login session between different spiders by it's design.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved above logic by setting prase callback of login spider to whatever spider I've to call once login spider get logged into site. I did make sure that every connecting spider has "parse"(same request callback function) method name.

I also used "argparse" to get an argument from CLI for next spider that needs to run after login.

LoadSpider.py:

```
import argparse
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from LogInSpider import LogInSpider

# Initiate the parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-fc", help="Follow Spider Class")
# Read arguments from the command line
args = parser.parse_args()
configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
runner.crawl(LogInSpider, parseClass=args.fc)
d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

LogInSpider.py :

```
from SelectProduct import SelectProduct
Class LogInSpider(scrapy):
   name = 'DomainLogin'
   allowed_domains = ['domain.io']
   start_urls = ['https://www.domain.io/signin']

   def __init__(self, parseClass=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LogInSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parseClass = parseClass

   def parse(self, response):
      return FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
      }, callback=eval(self.parseClass).parse)

Class SelectProduct(scrapy):
   # Crawl and select products
```

Command:

python3 LoadSpider.py fc="SelectProduct"